# use tag to combine @objc func methods

Tags: swift, tags, uipangesturerecognizer, func

My code declares 2 different @objc func methods using UIPan gestureRecongnizzer. I would think there would be a way to use just 1 objc func method using a tag. All the function currently does is move the imageview around. I dont know if tag is the best way and I am open to other solutions I just want 1 func. Specifically look at pgGestureMethod and sgGestureMethod.

```
   var pg = UIImageView()
var pgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
var pgCon = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

var sg = UIImageView()
var sgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
var sgCon = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  [pg,sg].forEach({
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview($0)
        $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    })
    pgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.pgGestureMethod(_:)))
    pg.addGestureRecognizer(pgGesture)


    sgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.sgGestureMethod(_:)))
    sg.addGestureRecognizer(sgGesture)

}

    @objc func pgGestureMethod(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(pg)
    let tranistioon = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    pg.center = CGPoint(x: pg.center.x + tranistioon.x, y: pg.center.y + tranistioon.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero,in: self.view)


}
@objc func sgGestureMethod(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    let tranistioon = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    sg.center = CGPoint(x: sg.center.x + tranistioon.x, y: sg.center.y + tranistioon.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero,in: self.view)


}
```

Comment: Why do you not move `sg` to front as well? Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gesture recognisers have a [`view`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624212-view) property that refers to the view to which they are added, so you don't even need a tag!

Just use one single action method like this:

```
@objc func pgGestureMethod(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    // I replaced every "pg" with "sender.view!"
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)
    let tranistioon = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + tranistioon.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + tranistioon.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero,in: self.view)
}
```

If not writing `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sg)` is actually intentional, you can simply check `sender.view!`:

```
@objc func pgGestureMethod(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.view == pg {
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(pg)
    }
    let tranistioon = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + tranistioon.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + tranistioon.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero,in: self.view)
}
```

Comment: he puts `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(pg)` only in case of `pgGestureMethod`.

Comment: @dimpiax I assumed that was just a typo. I don't see why _only_ moving `pg` to front is any useful. I guess we should let the OP clarify.

Comment: The sense to demonstrate complex approaches, probably newcomers will find it useful to distinct gestures to have a specific actions in one function.

Comment: @dimpiax Okay, it's quite trivial to handle anyway. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the Stackoverflow.

So in your case, you can understand which gesture was called from parameter in gesture function.

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
  var pg = UIImageView()
  var pgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
  var pgCon = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

  var sg = UIImageView()
  var sgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
  var sgCon = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    [pg,sg].forEach {[unowned self] in
      $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      self.view.addSubview($0)
      $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    pgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gestureDidRecognize(_:)))
    pg.addGestureRecognizer(pgGesture)

    sgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gestureDidRecognize(_:)))
    sg.addGestureRecognizer(sgGesture)
  }
}

@objc private extension SomeViewController {
  func gestureDidRecognize(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    guard let gestureView = gesture.view else { return }

    let transition = gesture.translation(in: view)

    switch gesture {
      case pgGesture:
        view.bringSubviewToFront(pg)

      default: break
    }

    gestureView.center = CGPoint(
      x: gestureView.center.x + transition.x, 
      y: gestureView.center.y + transition.y)

    gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
  }
}
```